# Битрикс узнать заказы по внешнему коду

Tags: битрикс

возможно ли в битриксе узнать id заказов по внешнему коду товара ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет внешнего кода товара не уверен, но по внешнему коду вы можете узнать ID товара, а по нему как раз очень легко можно получить заказы:

```
$rsOrder = CSaleOrder::GetList(array('ID' => 'DESC'), array('BASKET_PRODUCT_ID' => 174474));
```